# Hibernate Many-to-many: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship (Album and Artist to be precise).

Album

> cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
>   fetch = FetchType.EAGER

Artist

> cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
>   fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
>   mappedBy = "artists"

```
private void insertIntoDB(Object entity) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();

    try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.saveOrUpdate(entity);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public void insertEntity(Object entity) {
    for (Method method : entity.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(EntitySet.class)) {
            try {
                Set<Object> set = (Set<Object>) method.invoke(entity);

                List<Object> itemList = new LinkedList<>();
                List<Object> itemList2 = new LinkedList<>();

                for (Object entity1 : set) {
                    Object entity2 = this.getEntityById(entity1.getClass(), this.getEntityId(entity1));

                    if (entity2 != null) {
                        itemList2.add(entity1);
                        itemList.add(entity2);
                    }
                }
                set.removeAll(itemList2);
                set.addAll(itemList);
            } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    this.insertIntoDB(entity);
}
```

When I try and update an existing album I get the following error message:

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:638)
>       at com.phonoforce.tramory.Server.insertIntoDB(Server.java:61)
>       at com.phonoforce.tramory.Server.insertEntity(Server.java:110)

I was going through similar error messages but nothing seems to solve my problem. Changing the CascadeType just causes more/other problems. Another thing I tried was getting the entity that needs to be updated first, update the instance' values accordingly and use that instance to pass to insertEntity. Still same error. session.clear doesn't help either.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could upload more code, but from what you have posted, it looks like `set.removeAll(itemList2);` and `set.addAll(itemList);` is messing up the persistence.

Comment: You were right about `set.removeAll(itemList2);` and `set.addAll(itemList);` causing the problems. Fixed it by removing that part for updates.